# How to split WCF contract without duplication?

Tags: c#, wcf

I want to refactor service into multiple sub-services, separated by their business scope:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyService
{
    [OperationContract]
    int Method1();
    [OperationContract]
    int Method2();
}
```

And some **users already using it**, so I can't just bash in and say "goodbye" to them, refactoring everything on my way.

So, to avoid duplication, I use abstractions and interfaces beforehand and in this case I tried to separate contract to multiple interfaces and leaving main one as aggregator:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyService : IMySubService1, IMySubService2
{
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface IMySubService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    int Method1();
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface IMySubService2
{
    [OperationContract]
    int Method2();
}
```

I thought this will do the thing, but NO - it's breaking those clients, because now those methods located on different paths in WSDL, even though Im **hosting only IMyService**:

It was: `net.tcp://foobar/IMyService/Method1`

It became: `net.tcp://foobar/IMySubService1/Method1`

And that's a problem. I can't separate my contract into interfaces without duplication of code (one for implementation, and one explicitly aggregated for contract), any way I can solve it?

Comment: Refactor your business logic so that you can use it on as many endpoints you wish, the service contract should be just a thin layer anyway and propagate the call to the actual service, which should not have any clue if its running on top of wcf.

Comment: Im refactoring, thank you. Any suggestions about splitting contract without code duplication, or why WCF hosting interfaces which I didn't ask and not aggregated one?

Comment: If you want to keep the backwards compatibility to old contract AND provide new separate contracts, then there is not much you can do about that, just minimize the damage on the wcf service layer and share code amongst separated contracts.

Comment: Yes, I want exactly that. I thought maybe there is a way to tell WCF to send aggregated WSDL instead of multiple ones separated by interfaces

Comment: @eocron *don't* do that. There is no duplication here - you don't just have different service versions, those are completely different *services*. Inheritance is a *very* strong coupling that will prevent you from evolving the new services independently. You *can* reuse the same DTOs up to the point you discover the new services require changes to the DTOs as well. The *business* functionality, the *actual* request processing can probably be the same for both endpoints

Comment: I don't want new services, neither extend them, I want to pertain practice (aggregated interface) used by other team members, but need to internally simplify project (split interfaces).

Comment: @eocron imagine you have a MyOperationWorker class that accepts requests for operations from either interface, or separate workers per operation. These would be able to receive requests from any interface

Comment: If you think that ServiceContract means I 'ask' for new service, you are wrong. Without this attribute WCF complains, that's all. I added it only for it to stop complaining. But I didn't expect it would host my interfaces on different paths.

Comment: @eocron you *asked* for new services. WCF *did* aggregate the new interfaces as you told it to. A service is *defined* by the interface that has the `ServiceContract` attribute. You told WCF you want `IMyService` to expose two other services

Comment: @eocron warnings mean you did something wrong. This isn't about WCF or inheritance. It's about proper service design. If you don't agree go ahead - what happens next Monday when someone asks for a new parameter for Method2 ?

Comment: Nothing. It is model (aka request dto, every method is accepting and returning dto, I omitted it for simplicity), so I will add it. Adding new method? Not a problem too.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to do it this way:

```
[ServiceContract(Name = nameof(IMyService))]
public interface IMyService : IMySubService1, IMySubService2
{
}

[ServiceContract(Name = nameof(IMyService))]
public interface IMySubService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    int Method1();
}

[ServiceContract(Name = nameof(IMyService))]
public interface IMySubService2
{
    [OperationContract]
    int Method2();
}
```

Now WSDL generated correctly.